# Get the email address from SharePoint list and build Table inside Power Apps instead of hard-coding the values

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas, power-platform

We have the following Collection which contain a Type and Table of Email addresses inside Power App formula, with email addresses been hard coded, as follow:

```
ClearCollect(
    varUserForContracts,
    {
        Type: "Admin",
        Emails: Table(
            {UEmail: "app.admin@.org"},
            {UEmail: "*****.org"},
            {UEmail: ".org"},
            {UEmail: "*****.org"},
           {UEmail: "app.admin@.org"},
            {UEmail: "*****.org"},
            {UEmail: ".org"},
            {UEmail: "*****.org"},
        )
    }
);
```

Now instead I created a SharePoint list which include all the above emails:

[image]

So how can I build the same Collection but to populate the table values from the values inside the SharePoint list?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this formula:

```
ClearCollect(
    varUserForContracts,
    {
        Type: "Admin",
        Emails: ForAll(SharePointListSource, {UEmail: Title})
    }
);
```

Where `SharePointListSource` is the name of your SharePoint list data source.

**Documentation**: [ForAll function in Power Apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-forall)

Comment: Hi @JohnJohn, did you try this solution? Is it working for you?